# Linq to Dynamics - compare two properties in where clause

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am using Dynamics sdk dll's ver 5.0.9689.2165 and trying to use `Linq`
to get all Accounts where the `Account.XDate` is less than the `Account.YDate` (both are custom `DateTime` properties - I use the genenerated proxy classes in project to access these) from a Dynamics Online account.

I have this basic expression:

```
var accounts = myOrganizationServiceContext.CreateQuery<Account>().Where(a => a.XDate < a.YDate)
```

But I get the exception below when it gets processed - can't you compare 2 Entity properties up on the server?

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  Message=variable 'a' of type 'Account' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
  Source=System.Core
  StackTrace:
       at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.Reference(ParameterExpression node, VariableStorageKind storage)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(ReadOnlyCollection`1 nodes)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1 node)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda, DebugInfoGenerator debugInfoGenerator)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.CompileExpression(LambdaExpression expression)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateExpressionToValue(Expression exp, ParameterExpression[] parameters)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateExpressionToConditionValue(Expression exp, ParameterExpression[] parameters)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateWhereCondition(BinaryExpression be, FilterExpressionWrapper parentFilter, Func`2 getFilter, Boolean negate)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateWhere(String parameterName, BinaryExpression be, FilterExpressionWrapper parentFilter, Func`2 getFilter, List`1 linkLookups, Boolean negate)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateWhereBoolean(String parameterName, Expression exp, FilterExpressionWrapper parentFilter, Func`2 getFilter, List`1 linkLookups, BinaryExpression parent, Boolean negate)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateWhere(String parameterName, BinaryExpression be, FilterExpressionWrapper parentFilter, Func`2 getFilter, List`1 linkLookups, Boolean negate)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateWhereBoolean(String parameterName, Expression exp, FilterExpressionWrapper parentFilter, Func`2 getFilter, List`1 linkLookups, BinaryExpression parent, Boolean negate)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateWhere(QueryExpression qe, String parameterName, Expression exp, List`1 linkLookups)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.GetQueryExpression(Expression expression, Boolean& throwIfSequenceIsEmpty, Boolean& throwIfSequenceNotSingle, Projection& projection, NavigationSource& source, List`1& linkLookups)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.Execute[TElement](Expression expression)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.GetEnumerator[TElement](Expression expression)
```

at my call was here

InnerException:

Comment: You mentioned that YDate and XDate are *custom* properties. What does this mean? Are they also columns in your table, or are they properties in your class that you added manually? If the latter, then yes, EF cannot translate this to SQL.

Comment: In Dynamics, you can add custom fields to an Entity type. In this case, we have added DateTime fields to Account. This was done in Dynamics. I used the Dynamics sdk tool crmsvcutil.exe to generate strongly-typed proxy classes, and those classes wrap all fields, defualt and custom.

I can compare either property to a constant date, I just can not use one property against the other.

Answer (score 4):

This represents a limitation of the CRM Linq provider (yet again). [Per Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328328.aspx#limitations):

> **where**
>   The left side of the clause must be an attribute name and **the
>   right side of the clause must be a value**. You cannot set the left side
>   to a constant. Both the sides of the clause cannot be constants.

To solve your particular problem using the Linq provider, you might have to gather the entire `AccountSet` in memory, then use regular Linq methods against the result to get the final result you're after.

```
var accounts = myOrganizationServiceContext
    .CreateQuery<Account>()
    .Select(a => new { a.AccountId, a.XDate, a.YDate })
    .ToList();

var filteredAccounts = accounts
    .Where(a => a.XDate < a.YDate);
```