# LINQ compare 2 different fields from 2 aliases ERROR

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm

I hope to explain myself.

Why in LINQ I can't compare 2 different fields from 2 different tables (aliases), is there a problem with such action?

Let's say I have the following code :

```
return (from v in ctx.Xrm.rms_account_vehicleSet
        join j in ctx.Xrm.rms_jurisdictionSet on v.rms_l_jurisdiction.Id equals j.rms_jurisdictionId
        where v.jurisdiction_number == j.jur_number
        select v).FirstOrDefault();
```

I get an error:

> Typea`2[&lt;>f__AnonymousType9`2[Rms.Crm.Common.DataModel.RmsSchema.rms_account_vehicle,Rms.Crm.Common.DataModel.RmsSchema.rms_jurisdiction]' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the full class, the function or the relevant code so we can see what are you doing.

Comment: Try updating the early bound entities class file to see if properties have changed/renamed.

Comment: try it already, still the same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq to Dynamics - compare two properties in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874133/linq-to-dynamics-compare-two-properties-in-where-clause)