# Querying dynamics OrganizationService context 'referenced from scope..' linq exception

Tags: linq, microsoft-dynamics

When I query Microsoft Dynamics OrganizationServiceContext the following way:

```
from summary 
in Context.service_summarySet
join claim in Context.claimSet on summary.claim.Id equals claim.Id 
where claim.TransactionCurrencyId.Id != summary.TransactionCurrencyId.Id
select claim
```

I get an error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'variable '<>h__TransparentIdentifier0' of type '<>f__AnonymousType3`2[xxx]' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined'

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq to Dynamics - compare two properties in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874133/linq-to-dynamics-compare-two-properties-in-where-clause)

Comment: That's right! Many thanks.

Comment: By the way, it's a huge limitation.